# Ubuntu 14.04 startup difficulty

Tags: 14.04, startup, init.d, dlna

I installed Universal Media Server 3.6 on ubuntu 14.04 desktop. What I want to do is, to launch it during startup. How to add this into startup? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've already installed Java. If not, you can execute the following command to install the OpenJDK JRE (an open source alternative for Oracle's Java):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Follow the these instructions to start Universal Media Server at startup.

1. Open your Dash
2. Search for `Startup Applications` and open it
3. Click on `Add`
4. Enter the following:

   ```
   Name:    Universal Media Server
   Command: java -jar /path/to/ums.jar
   Comment: Start Universal Media Server
   ```

   *Replace `/path/to/ums.jar` by the actual path to `ums.jar`.*
5. Click on `Add`

Comment: are you sure about .jar? maybe ums.sh?

Comment: Oh, could be, I downloaded it quickly, saw a `.jar` and assumed that was the main binary. If you can confirm it doesn't work I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I did as you said, but neither .sh nor .jar didn't work. i mean application not launched on startup.